# Oracle of Ages 3DS Linked game items

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-ages

Ok, so I have a rather dumb question. I recently bought both Oracle of Ages and Seasons on the 3DS after having owned Seasons on the Gameboy. Now I've already beat Seasons, and I'm attempting to do a Linked Game. I've typed in the password, started out with the four heats and all, but I only have a level 1 Wooden Sword. I beat Seasons with the Noble Sword, and everything I'm reading says it should have transferred. So my question is this:

When playing a linked Oracle game do you automatically start with the sword you had in the game you beat, or are you given it later?

Answer (score 1):

> "In a Linked Game, Link begins his adventure with his Wooden Sword, and
>   with four Heart Containers instead of three."
>   [Wiki page this was taken from](http://zeldawiki.org/Linked_Game)

You do not transfer weapons across you can get rings back though with the help of either the Red Snake or the Blue Snake at Vasu Jewelers.

The Red Snake transfers the rings by giving Link a Ring Secret, which transfers the rings when told to the Red Snake in the opposing game.